# fetching data react native

Tags: react-native, fetch

apologising if this has been asked, I am totally new in react native...

I have simple app that is rendering some categories and data is in one js file in the object with arrays:

```
export default tabs = {
    categories: [
        { id: 'sample', title: 'sample' },
        { id: 'sample2', title: 'sample2' },
    ],
    deals: [
        { id: 'sample', title: 'sample' },
        { id: 'sample2', title: 'sample2' },
    ],
};
```

I wanted to use the same file just to connect to API and fetch data.

I tried many things something like:

```
import React from 'react';
const APIcategories = '......';
export default {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('inside... ');
        fetch(APIcategories)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => this.setState({ data: json }));
    },
};
```

it just never get anything in the log... tried many other methods nothing..

anybody had anything similar

Appreciate in advance!

I managed so far without errors:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const APIcategories = 'https://.......';

class SomeClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            error: null,
        };
        this.arrayholder = [];
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.someGetRequest();
    }
    someGetRequest = () => {
        console.log('inside------');
        fetch(APIcategories)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) =>
                this.setState({ data: res.results, error: res.error || null })
            );

        this.arrayholder = res.results;
        console.log(arrayholder);
    };
}
console.log('File opened---------');
export default SomeClass;
```

Comment: You used a default export for your object so you can import it like this: `import tabs from './tabs'`

Comment: `export default tabs = { }` is a syntax error. default export would look like `export default { }`

Comment: yes exactly, I am using it like that, but I want to connect to API to fetch data instead of hardcodded data. My intention is to leave rest of the code as it is, as it is forking fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class and then actually use it with its methods..

```
class SomeClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      error: null,
    };

    this.arrayholder = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.someGetRequest();
  }

  someGetRequest = () => {
    const url = `https:...`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: res.results,
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false,
        });
        this.arrayholder = res.results;
        console.log(res.results)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });

      });
  };

 export default SomeClass;
```

This code has been already tested with expo-cli 3.18.4

Comment: class SomeClass extends Component {
 componentDidMount() {'''        
  this.someGetRequest();
 }
 someGetRequest = () => {
  fetch(APIcategories)
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((data) => {
    this.setState({ data: data });
   })
   .catch((error) => console.log(error))
   .done();
  console.log(data);
 };
}

export default SomeClass; in the log I have nothing

Comment: Well if thats all your class is you didnt define the state. check the updated answer

Comment: thanks for help! Really appreciated.. I am getting error: Unexpected token expected ',' error: res.error || null

Comment: Well yeah if you want to add anything with the setState function so you can use something like loading or whatever you define in your state. You can just remove the , after null. if you think the answer is right and was helpful to you please accept it so other people can find it too.

Comment: OK I edited my question with new code... easier to read, this how far I got without errors, I am just getting last console.log "file opened.... " no other logs what's so ever. Thank so much for helping me as this is totally first time I am doing this..

Comment: also I cannot add .catch(error => { 
      //log whatever

        this.setState({ error }); as I cannot get my code to work with it.

Comment: Okay. Copy and paste and change your https url. I just tested this code and works fine.

Comment: As far as your previous code you should access the  arrayholder with this.arrayholder not just arrayholder! anyway you can log it with res.results

Comment: Thanks for all help, code is not returning any errors. project has menu and in menu tabs for navigation. Inside Tabs there is: import defaultMenu from '../constants/tabs'; this was my original file that I started from with hard-codded tabs, This file that I am working in is meant to replace hard-codded data with real one. when I try to log in console newly built defaultMenu in parent file I am getting '[Function SomeClass]'. but I am not getting any of the logs that we put in the code like 'console.log(res.results)'..

Comment: So I am not sure if data is fetched from API at all.. so I can handle it then and create object with array for navigation. Thanks for all effort, do you have any idea why I am not seeing any logs..

Comment: Just create a class and import it into the your main file to work with. But this is a totally different question please accept this answer and ask the next one.

Comment: from the naming convention it seems like defaultMenu is just a dummy data.
I think what you need is to access the https response within your class and then update your view. with the render method. so before returning the actual view return a loading screen and then fetch your data then update your views with correct data, username, extra data.